# How can I make sshuttle working on a dedicated IP of other VPN service?

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, vpn, openvpn

This is the first time I use the sshuttle.
I am running into an issue working with sshuttle.
I run the sshuttle to connect my local with a remote server on my local machine.
I can access the server by using ssh and pem file.
I used the following command on my MacOS.

`sshuttle --dns -vr dev 10.0.0.0/0 --ssh-cmd 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/dev.pem'`

I have set ssh config to use the **dev** hostname in .ssh/config file

```
host dev
    HostName xx.xxx.xx.xx
    user root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dev
```

But I couldn't connect my local to the remote server, even all the internet traffic keeps loading and never loads anything.

I am using a dedicated IP on VPN service (PureVPN). Wihtout VPN, sshuttle is working well so meaning that running sshuttle on top of other VPN service is a problem?
I don't think it's a problem since it's a dedicated IP. And if it's a problem, how can I address this issue since I must use the dedicated IP for an another service.
If you have faced the same issue before, please let me know.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of what you mentioned there could be two things that can be the cause. One, the credentials that are given to you by the third party hosting are incorrect. But since you mentioned that you are able to access the sshuttle without a VPN, this clearly indicates that you need to get your dedicated IP approved from the hosting service if it's not marked spam. If you are looking for a dedicated IP VPN service provider try Ivacy.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I've already purchased a dedicated IP service (PureVPN) that I mentioned above. I made the IP address approved on the hosting server, that's why I am concerning. And the credentials are correct since I could connect the sever by using ssh. The trouble is only sshuttle is not working on the dedicated IP address, but sshuttle is working without the VPN service.